# setprogname in Linux

Tags: c, linux, function, unix

In Unix I know that there are functions `setprogname` and `getprogname`.  Both are for setting and getting the program name respectively.  They are found in the library `stdilib.c`.  I was wondering if Linux has these functions built in as well because I cannot get them to run on the Linux machine (Ubuntu 10.04).  Are these functions available?  The code is below in case the man pages I found online didn't tell the whole story and I didn't add something that I needed.
Thanks!

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500

#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<sys/types.h>

#include<errno.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    setprogname(argv[0]);
```

Comment: That appears to be something specific to BSD-based systems and thus not available on Linux.

Comment: Those functions do not appear in POSIX: <http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/setprogramname.html>, so they are not part of Unix, but perhaps some different things based on Unix?

Answer (score 4):

From the [*BSD man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/setprogname/) about `{set,get}progname` :

> The getprogname() and setprogname() functions manipulate the name of
>   the
>        current program.  They are used by error-reporting routines to produce
>        consistent output.

If you want to customize the program name for error reporting with `error` and `error_at_line` you can declare and set `error_print_progname` variable as [described in the glibc manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#Error-Messages) :

> As mentioned above the error and error_at_line functions can be
>   customized by defining a variable named error_print_progname.
>
> — Variable: void (*) error_print_progname (void) If the
>   error_print_progname variable is defined to a non-zero value the
>   function pointed to is called by error or error_at_line. It is
>   expected to print the program name or do something similarly useful.
>
> The function is expected to be print to the stderr stream and must be
>   able to handle whatever orientation the stream has.
>
> The variable is global and shared by all threads.

Edit: I just check the gnulib manual about `{set,get}progname` and `error_print_progname` :

> This variable is missing on all non-glibc platforms: MacOS X 10.5, FreeBSD 6.0,
>   NetBSD 5.0, OpenBSD 3.8, Minix 3.1.8, AIX 5.1, HP-UX 11, IRIX 6.5, OSF/1 5.1,
>   Solaris 11 2011-11, Cygwin, mingw, MSVC 9, Interix 3.5, BeOS.

Answer (score 3):

Tried this on ubuntu 12.04 and it works:

Install the `libbsd-dev` package. Then try compiling the following code:

```
//filename=somec.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <bsd/stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    if(argc>1)
            setprogname((char*)argv[1]);
    printf("Program name is: %s\n",getprogname());
    return 0;
```

}

Using this set of arguments:

```
gcc somec.c -o somec -lbsd
```

This works for me.

Comment: By using the libbsd overlay mode (which is the recommended mode), you do not need to use the libbsd-specific header paths, which will make the code more portable. Check the libbsd(7) man page for information on how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [libbsd](http://libbsd.freedesktop.org/wiki/) on GNU/Linux to get access to these and other useful utility functions from *BSD operating systems.